# How to set css values from PHP variables in Wordpresss / Divi

Tags: php, css, wordpress, variables, dynamic

In my functions.php file is set colors with a color picker. That works because i see the color's hex when i echo them:
`<?php echo esc_attr( get_option('primary_color', '#ffffff') ); ?>`

Then i have the dynamic-css.php file that should set the H1 color according to the 'primary_color'

```
<?php header("Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8");
$primary_color = get_option( 'primary_color', '#ffffff' );?>
h1 {
background-color: <?php= $primary_color; !important ?>;
}
```

This php file is enqueud from my functions.php (the dynamic-css.php is located in the main directory from the child theme)

```
function enqueue_dynamic_styles() { wp_enqueue_style( 'dynamic-styles', get_theme_file_uri( '/dynamic-css.php' ), array(), false, 'all' ); } 
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_dynamic_styles' );
```

It doesnt change the colors however.
When i inspect the H1 i see the following error:

[www.4uwerkplaats.nl/:69](http://www.4uwerkplaats.nl/:69)          GET https://www.4uwerkplaats.nl/amelkoto/wp-content/themes/Divi-child-standaard/dynamic-css.php?ver=6.1.1 net::ERR_ABORTED 500

Why ?

Comment: Open your URL directly and observe the 500 error. This is the 'Internal Server Error' and i bet it is cause of `get_option` function. In this scenario your script is beeing run independently from WP, it knows nothing about WP and `get_option` function is not defined for it. Anyways this approach is kinda weird. You don't need dynamic styles here, you need to generate static CSS file every time the CSS related option is changed from admin area.

Comment: An alternative to what Jared said is to just kick out a `<style>` tag in the head with these. Sure, you lose a little bit of CSS minification efficiency, but unless you’ve got hundreds of these it probably doesn’t matter. If you do this, consider [CSS custom properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*), which are effectively CSS variables and are perfect for default but overridable values.

Comment: I changed dynamic-css.php to avoid using the get option. It now is get_theme_mod:

<code>
<?php
header("Content-Type: text/css; charset=utf-8");

$primary_color = '#ffffff'; // Default value
$primary_color_option = get_theme_mod( 'primary_color' );
if ( $primary_color_option ) {
    $primary_color = $primary_color_option;
}
?>

h1 {
    background-color: <?php echo $primary_color; ?> !important;
}
</code>